# Is "~A=>B" a horn clause?

Tags: horn

I just get confused for the definition of horn clause.
Is "~A=>B" a horn clause? If we convert it into disjunction forms, it will be "AvB" which is not a horn clause.

So I wonder whether it is a horn clause. Thanks.

Comment: This might be more appropriate on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

~AvB would be a horn clause. Which is equivalent to A=>B.
(At most one positive literal)

Comment: ... so you are saying ~A=>B is not a Horn Clause.

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand, ~A=>B would not be a horn clause.

Answer (score 0):

A Horn clause is a disjunction of literals with at most one positive literal, i.e.

```
~p1(...) \/ ~p2(...) \/ ... \/ ~pn(...) [ \/ p(...) ]
```

This can be, just for facilitating readability, written as

```
p(...) <= p1(...), p2(...), ..., pn(...).
```

So, if A and B are atoms, `B <= ~A` is *not* a Horn clause since this corresponds to the logical form `A \/ B` which has *two* positive literals.

The other way round, there are *only positive literals* allowed in the form written with "`=>`" and commas, and at most one literal / atom in the head of the implication. If there is no atom in the head, the clause is a *query clause* which is also legal.